# How to embed localization resource files into the main assembly in a .NET 7 WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

Following [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/main/Globalization%20and%20Localization/LocalizationResources), I've included some localization resource files in the `.csproj` file of my WPF app:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UICulture>en</UICulture>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="locale.en.restext" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="locale.es.restext" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="locale.fr.restext" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I can then create a `ResourceManager` instance and use `.GetString( String, CultureInfo )`.

The fallback mechanism works [more or less as advertised](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/package-and-deploy-resources#the-resource-fallback-process). ***Except...*** The ultimate fallback to the default UICulture doesn't seem to work - even when I include the following attribute in my classes:

```cs
[assembly:NeutralResourcesLanguage( "en" ) ]
```

And I'm fairly sure that's because my `.en.restext` file is getting built as a satellite assembly, rather than included in the main assembly.

```
PS > Get-ChildItem .\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows

    Directory: C:\Users\user\path\to\proj\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----          2023-05-18    23:56                en
d----          2023-05-18    23:56                es
d----          2023-05-18    23:56                fr
-a---          2023-05-18    23:56            679 Proj.deps.json
-a---          2023-05-18    23:56           6144 Proj.dll
-a---          2023-05-18    23:56         154624 Proj.exe
-a---          2023-05-18    23:56          12888 Proj.pdb
-a---          2023-05-18    23:56            266 Proj.runtimeconfig.json
```

Especially since if I include the following in my classes, then the fallback mechanism works perfectly:

```cs
[assembly:NeutralResourcesLanguage( "en", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite )]
```

So how do I specify in my `.csproj` file that a localized resource should be included in the main assembly, rather than in a satellite assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some more futzing around and trying to make sense of [this horror](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/3af6804637c057bf46bddccf23f1ede027885088/src/Tasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets)... I think I've cracked it.

Quite simply, when I specify the following in my `.csproj` file:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
    <UICulture>en</UICulture>
<!-- ... -->
```

Then it means I should name the "Neutral Culture" resource file without its identifying `en` suffix. Meaning it would appear in the `.csproj` ***not*** like this:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
    <EmbeddedResource Include="locale.en.restext" />
<!-- ... -->
```

But ***like this:***

```xml
<!-- ... -->
    <EmbeddedResource Include="locale.restext" />
<!-- ... -->
```

When I do this, it gets compiled into the main assembly.

And the ultimate fallback for `.GetString( String, CultureInfo )` works perfectly without specifying:

```cs
[assembly:NeutralResourcesLanguage( "en", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite )]
```

Props to Microsoft for open-sourcing so much of their .NET code. (Even when it's cryptic stuff, like the MSBuild definitions.)

I'm grateful that I no longer have to manually pre-compile `.restext` files with `resgen`, as so much of the documentation still says.

Generally, their documentation is top-drawer.

But I do think they ought to update the pages describing Resources and Localization for SDK-style projects.